# How and where in the code should I use the loop bool flag to decide if to loop or to make once movement between the waypoints?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The goal is to be able to decide if to loop or to move only once between the waypoints.
I added the loop bool flag for that.

Added the most details I can.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] targets;
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool countOrigPosAsWaypoint = true;
    public bool startFromFirstPositionOnStart = false;
    public bool goForward = true;
    public bool loop = true;

    private List<Vector3> pos = new List<Vector3>();
    private List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
    private int index = 0;
    private List<GameObject> objectsToMoveCopy = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (lineRenderer != null)
        {
            pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();
        }
        else
        {
            if (countOrigPosAsWaypoint == true)
            {
                pos.Add(transform.position);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < targets.Length; i++)
            {
                pos.Add(targets[i].position);
            }
        }

        if (startFromFirstPositionOnStart == true)
        {
            transform.position = pos[index];
        }

        if (pos.Count <= 1)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Targets list count must be more then 1");
        }
    }

    List<Vector3> GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount].ToList();
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions.ToArray());


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go == true && pos.Count > 1)
        {
            Moving();
        }
    }

    void Moving()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;
            newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
            if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
            {
                // when you hit a waypoint:
                if (goForward)
                {
                    bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Count - 1;
                    if (!atLastOne) index++;
                    else { index--; goForward = false; }
                }
                else
                { // going backwards:
                    bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                    if (!atFirstOne) index--;
                    else { index++; goForward = true; }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        transform.position = newPos;
    }
}
```

If true make a loop between the waypoints either backward or forward and if false just move forward or backward once and stop the last/first waypoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ld say e.g. at

```
if (!atLastOne) 
{
    index++;
}
else if(!loop)
{
    stillTraveling = false;
} 
else
{ 
    index--;  
    goForward = false; 
}
```

and accordingly

```
if (!atFirstOne) 
{
    index--;
}
else if(!loop)
{
    stillTraveling = false;
}
else 
{ 
    index++; 
    goForward = true; 
}
```

And probably remove the current

```
else
{
    stillTraveling = false;
}
```

as it will be the case most of the time between the points.

---

In general though: Currently this will all happen in one single frame without any animation... This should probably rather happen in a Coroutine or only do one step at a time .. not in a while loop at all.

Comment: I will try to transfer it to a Coroutine.

Comment: There is a memory leak with this solution. I tried it and the editor freeze not responding and it's taking over 1GB of memory usage then I need to force shut down the editor. when I switched back to the original code in my question it's working fine.

Comment: Can you show me please how to change it to use Coroutine instead in the Update ?

Comment: I tried this using coroutine but the transform is not moving : https://pastebin.com/6BQa1dQj